# Quais as diferenças entre .bat e .cmd?

Tags: cmd, batch

Raramente vemos arquivo `.cmd`, mas ao abri-lo, vemos que seu conteúdo é muito próximo de um `.bat`.

- Qual o motivo dessa semelhança ?
- Quais seriam as principais diferenças entre eles ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A única diferença entre `.cmd` e `.bat`, é que no `.cmd` a variável `ERRORLEVEL`
munda também no caso de comandos bem sucedidos afetado pelas **extenções de comando** quando ativada (**PATH/APPEND/PROMPT/SET/ASSOC**).

Já no `.bat` a variável `ERRORLEVEL` só mudará no caso de um erro.

[Fonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file)

Comment: Sacha, quando "copiar" a resposta de algum lugar, é legal postar a fonte. Também deve-se prestar atenção nas "traduções" incorretas. Já acertei para você ok.

Comment: Editado ! Obg ! Amigo desculpa se não de pra entender eu sou de idioma francês !